# Western Digital Elements Fell - Computer won't recognize it, but it's not making any noise either

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a 2 TB Western Digital Elements drive that fell flat off the top of my desktop onto the floor (cable got snagged) while plugged in (not sure if it was actively being read from/written to but lets assume it was). I unplugged it and when I tried plugging it back in the led lights up, but the the disk does not seem to spin or make any audible noises and the computer won't see it. Also when I move the drive around/gently rock it (unplugged) I can not hear anything loose.

What are the chances that the drive is OK or mostly recoverable? Or is it pretty safe to assume that it's toast. I don't want to keep testing it because there is important information  (not yet backed up) on the drive and I do not want to ruin it further...

Thanks!

Comment: Might still be fine and just a damaged PCB, try taking the case off and plugging it into an on-board port

Comment: @50-3 That's what I'm hoping... but I'm afraid that if I try that and there really is something more physically wrong I will end up screwing it up more... thoughts?

Comment: @ysigala the device is likely already beyond hope you have very little to lose if anything the best case the drive still works and hooking it up as a normal drive is likely your only option

Comment: Personal thoughts are if a case has screws it was built to be disassembled if it doesn't it was designed to be a challenge  :)

Answer (score 2):

As noted removing the case and trying may yield positive results. It may be the USB connector is damaged due to the fall or the circuit board. The cases can be a challenge to open

You also might try something that has worked for me in the past

While it does not always work I have had success placing the drive in a freezer for at least a few hours. Sometimes a few days helps. Place the drive in a Ziplock type bag and remove as much air as possible. Place the bag and drive in a freezer and leave it for at least a few hours.

Remove the drive from the bag and connect it as quickly as possible

It has sometimes worked after a few hours but it once took a couple of days, but I was able to recover data from several drives this way. Unfortunately, not always.

There is always an expert drive recovery company